# What does "[0;31m" means?

Tags: shell

I saw this string in many places,but what does it means ?

For example : https://github.com/ibnYusrat/my-linux-setup/blob/master/setup.sh

[example in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdcOM.png)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [ANSI escape sequence](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html). It's mainly used to colorize/format your shell's standard out. Please find a list of valid sequences [here](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html).
Regarding the title of this thread --> `\033[0;31m` start's to colorize your output red. Please be aware that you must reset your sequence with `\033[0m`.
See attached an example:
[image]

Comment: For anyone wondering how to view the file containing this on Windows, you can just cat it in Powershell